# Android - Automatic updating view when any change in database

Tags: android, database, listview

I am developing an android application where it shows a list of name from database and when database values are changed (inserting/deleting item) then View should automatically reflect that change.

I don't want polling and `Broadcast Receiver`.I want things like binding `ListView` to database. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your database entries do have unique ids and you do have a reference to the ListView while performing database actions you could tag your views in the ListView with those ids at the same time you do it with the names. When performing an insert or delete operation of your database you run a refresh function which iterates through your ListView. If the updated id matches one of the tagged views you refresh the data inside the view.